# Synchronization of two svn repositories

Tags: svn, repository, tortoisesvn

I want to create two svn repositories of single project (one is backup of other @ different location) and how to keep synchronized both with any code commit in one repository.

Comment: All commits will go to one repo only, or can go to both?

Comment: on both repositories..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my solution on wordpress

http://iacoware.wordpress.com/2009/10/02/howto-use-svnsync-to-mirror-a-repository-on-windows/

Answer (score 2):

You can install VisualSVN Server at both locations and configure [Multisite Repository Replication](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/features/multisite-replication/) feature to achieve this.

Multisite Repository Replication is based on VisualSVN Distributed File System (VDFS) technology which provides bidirectional, automatic and transparent repository replication between a master repository and a *writable* slaves.

Learn more at http://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00068/

Answer (score 0):

There's basically two solutions for what you want.

**Free solution**

One repo is the master and others are slaves.  The slaves can be used for reads and use svnsync to keep themselves in sync off the master.  The slaves have a `SVNMasterURI http://master.example.com/svn/repo` which provides the URI for the master server.  Writes will be proxied to the master.

[C. Michael Pilato has an excellent blog](http://blogs.collab.net/subversion/yesterday-at-th#.Us2qxl7Toac) post up about how to set this up.

But this isn't exactly what you're asking for (though the fact that the writes are only going to the master is mostly transparent to users).

Also note that this solution only works with DAV (http or https) access.

**Commercial Solution**

WANdisco (full disclosure: my employer) makes two products that are made to allow active-active use of Subversion repositories and keep them in sync for you.  They are called [SVN MultiSite](http://www.wandisco.com/subversion/multisite) and [SVN MultiSite Plus](http://www.wandisco.com/subversion/multisiteplus).  SVN MultiSite only supports DAV, but MultiSite Plus can support svnserve as well.

This does exactly what you want but unfortunately is not free.

Answer (score 0):

Create master slave architecture for your svn repos

**Slave**
Slave will use write through proxy for master server. So any commit to slave will go to master server instead.

**Master**

Master will use **post commit hook** to write back on slaves.


This needs that writing to slave should be initialized from master using 
**svn initialize** for first time. After that post commit hook will do the task (**svn sync command**).

So the structure goes like this
**From slave**

1. Checkout from slave. 
2. Commit to slave

3. Slave will redirect the commit to master

4. After commit has been done to master, master will update the slave

**From Master**

1. Checkout from master

2. Commit from master

3. After commit is completed master will update slave.

4. If slave is not up and running, you might need to execute post-commit hook again after bringing slave up.

This approach can be used for multiple slaves too. In  multiple slave all slave should use write through proxy to master and post commit hook of master should run command "svn sync" on all slaves